# How to replace a string by given a relation of original and return string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a file, and the pattern text is like `(1A0IA:0.42722,1AYLA:0.47152)`. I want to replace it with `(1A0IA,1AYLA)`.

I know I can do in this way:

`text` is string contain `(1A0IA:0.42722,1AYLA:0.47152)`

```
expression 1 : reduced_text = re.sub(r':\d+\.\d+\,',r',',text) 
output : (1A0IA,1AYLA:0.47152)
expression 2 : reduced_text = re.sub(r':\d+\.\d+\)',r')',reduced_text) 
output : (1A0IA,1AYLA)
```

Accutally I want to replace the pattern `:float,` only in `(ID:float,ID:float)`, but there exist some text containing `:float,` but not in this kind of string: `(ID:float,ID:float)`.

Does there exist an expression that can do like the following?

```
(string1:0.42722,string2:0.47152) -> (string1,string2)
```

The first `.{5}` is `string 1` ; the second `.{5}` is `string 2`

```
reduced_text = re.sub(r'\(.{5}:\d+\.\d+\,.{5}:\d+\.\d+\)',r'\(.{5}\,.{5}\)',text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are search groups (see for example *[Named Capturing Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)*).

With these you can do something like the following to get your IDs.

```py
re.findall('(?P<id1>.{5}):[\d\.]+,(?P<id2>.{5}):[\d\.]+', text)
```

Actually it is not necessary to name the capturing groups, thus `(.{5})...` would be sufficient here.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> '(' + ','.join(re.findall(r'[,\(]([^:]*):', s)) + ')'
'(1A0IA,1AYLA)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
import re
s = "(1A0IA:0.42722,1AYLA:0.47152)"
r = "([\d\w]{5}):[\d\.]+(,|\))"
re.sub(r, r'\1\2', s)
# '(1A0IA, 1AYLA)'
```